# DataSource Table prefix

Tags: grails

We have multiple applications which are using different Database.

So we decided to use only one Database for all the data, because some data across the applications belongs together.

That database would have around 100 tables and we want to use prefixes for the table, that we can see where this table belongs to.

I could change it in Mappings with `table: 'prefix_table'` but maybe there is a simplier way.

I thought maybe there is a way to set the table Prefix in the DataSource?

**EDIT**

Here is my DataSource config:

```
dataSource {
        pooled = true
        loggingSql = true
        driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
        username = "user"
        password = "pw"
        dbCreate = "update"  
        url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/test"
    }
```

Comment: Please can you advise the database technology that you are using?

Comment: I'm using an MySQL Database

Comment: For this purpose I'm using a sessionFactoryPostProcessor that registers a HibernateConfigPostProcessor that eventually changes table names of configured entities. I can drop the code here if you're interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See docs under 'CustomNamingStrategy':
http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#customNamingStrategy

Add to your project's DataSource.groovy:

```
hibernate {
    …
    naming_strategy = 'com.myco.myproj.CustomNamingStrategy'
}
```

Add this to your project src

```
package com.myco.myproj
import org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
import org.hibernate.util.StringHelper

class CustomNamingStrategy extends ImprovedNamingStrategy {

    String classToTableName(String className) {
        "prefix_" + StringHelper.unqualify(className)
    }
}
```